# How to change all the elements of a list that are equal?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

How can I replace all elements of a list which are equal to `c` to `t` in OCaml?

I have tried `List.filter` without success:

```
List.fold_right (fun c -> t) (List.filter c myLst) []
```

Does the `List` module contain a function for this task?

Comment: When you say 'changed by "t"', do you mean all elements `c` should be replaced with `t`? Should the new list contain all the non-`c` elements and every `c` should be replaced with a `t`?

Comment: Only every c. Non-c elements don't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` (see the [List module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html)):

```
open Printf;;

let l = ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'; 'c']
let l2 = List.map (fun x -> if (x = 'c') then 't' else x) l;;
List.iter (printf "%c ") l2;;
```

which prints

```
a b t d t
```

Comment: I believe you'd better use (x = 'c') rather than x == 'c' in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use List.fold_right, here is the way to do it:

```
let replace lst = List.fold_right (fun elmt accum -> 
    let e = if elmt = 'c' then 't' else elmt in
    e::accum
) lst [];;
      val replace : char list -> char list = <fun>
# replace ['a'; 'b'; 'c'];;
- : char list = ['a'; 'b'; 't']
```

Notice : Do NOT use == instead of = in OCaml, they have different meanings.
== tests for physical equality, but = tests for semantical equality. So when you use ==, it could return false even if the two values are semantically equal.